# Getting all source links from website with Flutter

Tags: http, parsing, flutter

I want to let Flutter parse a website with the parser and http package and after all links are collected I want to display all the pictures on a widget but I just cant get it to work. Does somebody know how to implement it into a program?

For example, I want to collect all img src links from this [link](https://www.instagram.com/alexanderwangny/).

I tried it like this:

```
class PictureParser extends StatefulWidget{  
  @override
  _PictureParserState createState() => _PictureParserState();
}

class _PictureParserState extends State<PictureParser>{
  List<String> list = List();

  void _getData() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://www.tgm.ac.at/');
    dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);

    var d = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    list = d.map((list) => d[0].attributes['src']).toList(); 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () {
              _getData();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Image.network(
            list[index],
            height: 200.0,
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```